# Sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

I already install *Java 1.8.0_111* (newest update), download *apache-maven-3.3.9* and *SonarQube-6.1* and put *sonar-web-plugin-2.5.0.476.jar* into sonarQube extension plugin.

I have a problem when running maven-sonar-scanner and I get this error Log.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-07T18:52:57+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 84M/885M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:
3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) on project sample: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonar
source.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar failed: An API incompatibili
ty was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plu
gin:3.1.1:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.ge
tConfiguration()Lorg/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1

[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource
/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.1.1/sonar-maven-plugin-3.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/apache/mave
n/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/pl
exus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aet
her/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/pl
exus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/pl
exus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/pl
exus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource
/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.7/sonar-scanner-api-2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/commons-lang/co
mmons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/david.vincent/.m2/repository/com/google/code
/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContaine
rException
```

I already delete and re-download all my repository using command *mvn clean install* but its not work. This is only error in one PC, the other PC work properly.

My project is using **Spring Boot Parent 1.4.1.RELEASE**, my full POM.XML file can be seen at this [SO link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839568/sonar-maven-plugin-can-not-set-sonar-sources-src-main-resources/)

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443875/failed-to-execute-goal-org-sonarsource-scanner-mavensonar-maven-plugin3-0-1so?rq=1), it should be plugin version problem, but I already download compatible version of SonarQube 6.1

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise maven-compilre-plugin-3.3, sonar-maven-plugin-3.1.1, apache-maven-3.3.9. This error only happen in my PC, the other PC is working properly.

Comment: Can you check on both via `mvn --version`?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T23:41:4
7+07:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"